# How can i merge two bitmap one over another at selected point on the first image in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawbitmap

How can i merge two different images as one. Also i need to merge the second image at a particular point on the first image. Is it posible in android??

Comment: post you required screen shot for help....

Comment: hi Md Abdul Gafur, I need to merge one image over another. I have done that.. but now i need to do the merging in such a manner that i can add the second image at a position where i need to place it...(eg:Suppose a persons picture as the first image and a bubble as the second image.. i need to place the bubble on the to of his head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

- Create a canvas object based from the bitmap.
- Draw another bitmap to that canvas object (methods will allow you
  specifically set coordinates).
- Original Bitmap object will have new data saved to it, since the
  canvas writes to it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this function can help you:

```
private Bitmap mergeBitmap(Bitmap src, Bitmap watermark) {
      if (src == null) {
         return null;
      }
      int w = src.getWidth();
      int h = src.getHeight();

      Bitmap newb = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas cv = new Canvas(newb);

      // draw src into canvas
      cv.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

      // draw watermark into           
      cv.drawBitmap(watermark, null, new Rect(9, 25, 154, 245), null);

      // save all clip
      cv.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

      // store
      cv.restore();

      return newb;
   }
```

It draws the water mark onto "src" at specific Rect.